# Spring AMQP Auto Scaling Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream

So I've been doing research on Spring AMQP and Spring Cloud Stream using a Topic Exchange. If I have that app in an AWS auto scaling group would extra instances of the app subscribe to the same exchange and receive duplicate messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumers don't "subscribe exchanges", they consume from queues that are bound to exchanges.

If the destination is in a group; the instances will compete for messages from the same queue. If there is no group, the consumer is anonymous and all instances will get the messages.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          group: consumer1
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the confusion on the terminology. I meant bind to an exchange but thank you for understanding my meaning. I guess I'll have to look more into binding groups.